# "Completed initial distribution of" bug when running - NetBeans 7.4

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, web, glassfish

I started with Java development. I created an EJB application running on a glassfish server. I’m using Netbeans 7.4 and GlassFish 4. When I run or deploy the project, Netbeans hangs at the stage

"Completed initial distribution of [project_name]", but the run doesn't complete :(

Did someone encounter the same problem? How to proceed? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not to be mean, but you should use Eclipse rather than NetBeans. I am not kidding, it is easier and faster. Link: http://www.eclipse.org/

If you feel the need to learn how to use Eclipse, check out thenewboston in YouTube:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CE8UIbb_4iM

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Actually, I've already used Eclipse before but it doesn't support database management. With NetBeans, you can create and manage databases, which is not included in Eclipse.